# database and calling activities

Tags: android

I have a main activity for example say MainPageActivity.Now there are many other activitites linked to it.And all the activities hase nodes for example motorola,iphone,samsung etc.And it has a switch yes and no which specifies shortcut. If the switch is on yes, than an entry is created in database and its shortcut hence will be shown on the MainPageActivity.And as soon as the switch is slipped to no than the datbase value should be deleted and hence shortcuts should not been shown. All the activities has such nodes and switch too. I have created all the database tables to..

What I should do now to update, delete and show the values ?

Comment: please post your database code ?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: i cannot post the code for some security issues. But i have made a table which has NodeId, NodeType(android,windows) Status and NodeName

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLiteOpenHelper and SQLiteDatabase to store the state of your nodes. If you have many activities for nodes then you can update that status of node in database in that activities which have motorola, iphone or samsung whenever it gets changed.

And in MainPageActivity you can retrieve state of each node in onResume() method and update the UI.